# Why changing branches results in uncommited changes?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I've got a really odd situation... it may be because I'm relatively new to git, but this seems wrong. Every time I change branches from the command line, I get a set of uncommitted changes (different depending which branch I checkout).

I'm working with a Stash repository ("Stash" the Git repository, like a private GitHub, not "git stash" the command). This repo has multiple branches: master / development / feature1, etc.

To be clear, I've made NO changes to any branches... I'm a brand-new user connecting on a brand new client, freshly installed. I'm just browsing the branches and making sure that each branch builds on my system.

Here are the commands I used:

```
git branch -a
```

This lists all the branches and initially showed I have "master" locally and other branches remote.

I then checked-out the development branch

```
git checkout -b development origin/development
git status
```

This shows me that I now have about 20 uncommitted changes, including some source files, project files and a few misc data files. Why? Is this normal git behavior?

I try to go back to master:

```
git checkout master
```

But this fails due to uncommitted changes. If I force it:

```
git checkout master -f
```

it seems to work fine and I'm back on the master branch with no uncommitted changes.

Really?!? The uncommitted changes are not even the diffs between the branch... only a subset. What can explain this behavior? And how can I stop it?

FYI, running **git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0** on Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost 100% sure this is related to the classic problem of Windows vs. Linux/Mac line endings -- i.e., the fact that when you hit the "Enter" key in Windows, you get a different character/set of characters than when you hit "Enter" in Linux or Mac. (If you're curious, [here's some information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) on that problem)

To know for sure if this is your problem, run a `git diff`. If the result shows that the lines taken away had the same content (or "look the same") as the lines added, then it's likely a whitespace issue.

Git knows about this problem, and will manage the line endings for you...if you tell it to. Try changing your `autocrlf` option:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

And see if the problem persists.

You may still need to re-normalize the repository for these differences. If so, [GitHub has a great article on this](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings). See the bottom section for details on re-normalizing.

(Oh, and in case I'm way off here, then update your question with examples of what you found in `git diff`, and we can use that to figure this out.)